# Asp .Net MVC application hosted in IIS and needed to be accessed from other machines in the same domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I am currently developing an application using ASP .NET MVC. I published that web application in IIS which is running on Windows server 2012 R2. I need the people from my organisation to access the website. I am using Windows Authentication and I searched in internet and I found i can access my website using the IP address. But how can I achieve Authentication? I can do it manually by adding a user in IIS but I dont want to do it. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You are saying "I am using Windows Authentication", and then you are asking "how can I achieve Authentication?". Please describe exactly the scenario you want to achieve.

Comment: I need the people from my organisation to access the website using their windows credentials.

Comment: Consider active directory integration to your web site. Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the ways to do this, which is a manual procedure using IIS Manager. To enable windows authentication you need the following:

1. Ensure your machine with IIS server is joined to domain
2. Open up IIS Manager, disable anonymous authentication and enable Windows Authentication. See the picture below on what the configuration page should look like. Basically all types of authentication are disabled, except Windows auth.

[image]